# No Configuration was provided Log4j loading

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Calling a Log4j wrapper api through tomcat container. I'm getting the following error

```
 ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at  position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class web.empire.erp.startup.ServerAccessor
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at empire.erp.server.subsystem.gateway.GatewayClient.logIn(GatewayClient.java:34)
at web.empire.erp.startup.ServerAccessor.contextInitialized(ServerAccessor.java:40)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: No Configuration was provided
at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:477)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:561)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:577)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:212)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:242)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:174)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:618)
at empire.erp.server.commons.logging.LogHandler.<clinit>(LogHandler.java:17)
... 11 more
```

It doesn't say that configFile is missing so that is not the problem. Can't seem to figure out what's wrong. The Following is my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration>

<Properties>
    <Property name="baseDir">c:\logs</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console">
      <PatternLayout>
         <pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n 
         </pattern>
      </PatternLayout>

    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/app.log"  filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
        <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
            <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
            <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log.gz" />
            <IfLastModified age="60d" />
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>

</Appenders>    

<Loggers>

    <Logger name="EmpireLogger" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" level="error"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>

</Configuration>


**EDIT**: classpath  
C:\Development\Tomcats\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Development\Hibernate\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Development\Hibernate\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Development\Hibernate\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Development\Tomcats\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\lib\tools.jar;C:\Development\Hibernate\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Development\Hibernate\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\classmate-1.3.0.jar;C:\Development\Hibernate\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Development\Hibernate\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Development\Hibernate\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Development\Hibernate\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar;C:\Development\Hibernate\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar;C:\Development\log4j2\apache-log4j-2.6-bin\log4j-api-2.6.jar;C:\Development\log4j2\apache-log4j-2.6-bin\log4j-core-2.6.jar;C:\Development\EclipseWorkSpaces\HomeDevWS\OptimalYou\bin
```

**UPDATE 2**: log after changing stack = trace in configuration tag

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
Jul 03, 2016 5:28:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class web.empire.erp.startup.ServerAccessor
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at empire.erp.server.subsystem.gateway.GatewayClient.logIn(GatewayClient.java:34)
at web.empire.erp.startup.ServerAccessor.contextInitialized(ServerAccessor.java:39)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: No Configuration was provided
at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:477)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:561)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:577)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:212)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:242)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:174)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:618)
at empire.erp.server.commons.logging.LogHandler.<clinit>(LogHandler.java:17)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Strange indeed! Can you change your configuration to add `<Configuration status="trace">` and post the resulting internal Log4j2 debug output printed to the console? Also, what does your classpath look like?

Comment: am getting java.lang.NullPointerException: No Configuration was provided on a info level log

Comment: -Dcatalina.base="C:\Development\EclipseWorkSpaces\HomeDevWS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1" -Dcatalina.home="C:\Development\Tomcats\apache-tomcat-8.0.33" -Dwtp.deploy="C:\Development\EclipseWorkSpaces\HomeDevWS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\Development\Tomcats\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\endorsed" -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:log4j2.xml  is my tomcat argument

Comment: Can you change your configuration to add `<Configuration status="trace">` and post the resulting internal Log4j2 debug output printed to the console? Also, what does your classpath look like? (You can obtain this by printing the value of System property `java.class.path`.)

Comment: added the classpath.

Comment: added stack trace. It seems like the xml is found but not being parsed properly. Hope the pattern is correct since it was copied from the documentation, didnt try to understand it

Comment: Thanks! Not sure but I suspect JBoss Logging. Can you move the Log4j 2.6 jars to the beginning of the classpath? (Also 2.6.1 has important bugfixes. Please upgrade.)

Comment: thanks will try that

Comment: Also strange that the console output doesn't have any TRACE or DEBUG statements detailing Log4j2 initialization even after you changed to `<Configuration status="trace">`. Is there no typo? (You said stack=trace instead of status.) Do you get more output when you set System property `log4j.StatusLogger.level` to `true`?

Comment: @RemkoPopma Solved. I had configured both the web application and tomcat with log4j2. It was conflict of jars. removed log4j from web app and now it works fine. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What was the conflict? Different versions?

Comment: No, I am guessing that tomcat would have loaded log4j config file and stored it in some manager's state during start up, but when retrieving logger from the LogManager, I think tomcat is reloading the class specified in the lib folder instead which doesn't know where the config file is.